# Navigator not rendering anything

Tags: react-native

I'm new to React Native but I can render screens, lists and I think I'm starting to understand the big picture.

However, I can't make this simple Navigator code to work and it's driving me crazy. It's the basic example you can find everywhere on the web, including the official docs:

```js
class RNTest extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Navigator
                initialRoute={{ title: 'My Initial Scene', index: 0 }}
                renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                    <Text>Hello</Text>
                }}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

No errors, no issues. All I get is a white screen.

Replacing the Navigator with a component, everything works. This navigator is refusing to render anything. Any hints on how to figure out what's going on?

Comment: try wrap it with `return`

Comment: Well, I feel dumb. It works. But why? And why no examples on the web include "return" in the renderScene tag? ... oh, thanks, btw!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

renderScene must have return value, you can do this:

```
renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
                    return <Text>Hello</Text>
            }}
```

or remove '{}' wrapping Text component

```
renderScene={ (route, navigator) => <Text>Hello</Text> } // Text component is return value
```

[Arrow functions](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html) maybe helpful, You need search 'Arrow function syntax'